# How to solve KeyError in Django?

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary, django-admin

I have multiple Apps in my Django website, And i want to get the data from all Apps, I definds all the apps in `settings.py` file, and i created a function in `admin.py` file for display the data.
But i am getting `Keyerror`, please check my code and let me know where i am Mistaking

here is my `settings.py` file code..

```
ADMIN_ORDERING = [
  ('manager', [
      'Products',
      'ProductTemplates',
 ]),
]
```

here is my `admin.py` file which is displaying the data in views..

```
def get_app_list(self, request):
    app_dict = self._build_app_dict(request)
    for app_name, object_list in settings.ADMIN_ORDERING:
        app=app_dict[app_name]
        app['models'].sort(key=lambda x: object_list.index(x['object_name']))
        yield app
```

i am getting error in this line `app=app_dict[app_name]` it's displaying `KeyError at/ manager`,
and `manager` is my django project `app name`

Comment: What is the name of the app that you are running?, maybe inspect the content of app_dict

Comment: if i do `return app_dict` then homepage is displaying, but data is not displaying, because data is coming from `for` loop...and my app name is `manager`, which is already defined in `INSTALLED_APP`

Comment: Can you print app_dict before the loop?

Comment: yes, that's working fine, but i want to display my app data through for loop

Comment: I want to see the output pls! Cause app_data should be a dict